# Can SVM be special case of PCA?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, machine-learning, svd, principal-component-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ two linearly separable finite subsets of a $K$-dimensional real vector space $V$ with orthonormal basis $A = \{a_1,\ldots, a_K\}$. The covariance matrix $\Sigma_A$ of the set $X \cup Y$ is just the representation of a symmetric bilinear form $Cov$ relative to the basis $A$. Let now $\Sigma_B$ be the matrix representing the same bilinear form relative to the orthonormal basis $B = \{b_1,\ldots, b_K\}$ formed by the normalized eigenvectors of $\Sigma_A$. Is it true that every hyperplane that separates $X$ and $Y$ with largest possible margin is necessarily normal to one of the vectors of the basis $B$ ?

If this was true then the technique of Support Vector Machines (SVM) would be a quick consequence of the application of $K$ different Principal Component Analysis (PCA), each one keeping ($K-1$)-dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a counterexample: [image: the red line is the line of best separation, while the black line is the affine subspace of maximum variance]

The red line is the line of best separation, while the black line is the affine subspace of maximum variance. The two subspaces are not orthogonal to each other.